# Question about an inverse system and its cone

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Say we have an [inverse system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit) of $(R_i,f_{ij})$ of (commutative,unital) rings and ring homomorphisms over $\mathbb{N}$. Let $L$ be a ring s.t. $R_i$ is a subring of $L$ for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Knowing this, can I say something about $(L,p_i)$ being a cone of $(R_i,f_{ij})$ ($p_i$ are the ring homomorphisms from $L$ to $R_i$) ? In particular, is there a way of deducing if the maps $p_i$ making $L$ into a cone of $(R_i,f_{ij})$ exist?

Comment: These things seem backwards. Did you want the $R_i$ to be quotients of $L$, otherwise the maps seem to be going the wrong way.

Comment: I did actually want subrings. In $f_{ij}$, $j \leq i  \in \mathbb{N}$ so the notation is different than that in the linked article. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I mean that the $p_i$ are going the wrong way to form a cone. They're going the right way for a cocone, but since you said you have an inverse system, and we usually take limits of those rather than colimits, I assume that's not relevant.

Comment: Seems like I misunderstand the definitions of a cone/cocone. [This](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#N4Igdg9gJgpgziAXAbVABwnAlgFyxMJZARgBoAGAXVJADcBDAGwFcYkQAZEAX1PU1z5CKcqWLU6TVuwBKAfSw8+IDNjwEiAJjESGLNohDyAVjwkwoAc3hFQAMwBOEALZIyIHBCTbJ+9nblgLGNuJXsnV0RRDy9Ed0Z6ACMYRgAFAXVhEAcsSwALHBAaPWlDNAUwkEcXJGjPbxoE5LSMoXZGGDtC4qkDFTlTbkpuIA), assuming that we can show it commutes, makes $L$ together with the maps $p_i$ ($i \in \mathbb{N}$)  into a cone. Is that false?

Comment: The diagram you linked shows a cone, but if the $p_i$ are maps making $R_i$ a subring of $L$, then they go $R_i\to L$, right?

Comment: Yeah, of course. I misunderstood some things, thank you for pointing it out.